# Problems starting an NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus

I've created a very simple NServiceBus console application to send messages. However I cannot start the bus as it complains with a very vague error about 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.

```
        Configure config = Configure.With();
        config = config.DefaultBuilder();
        config = config.BinarySerializer();
        config = config.UnicastBus();
        IStartableBus startableBus = config.CreateBus();
        IBus Bus2 = startableBus.Start(); // **barf**
```

It's driving me mad, what am I missing? I thought the DefaultBuilder should be filling in any blanks?

Comment: Consider posting the relevant parts of the stack-trace, to provide a little more information?

Comment: Stack trace didn't look very useful too much generic stuff in it

Comment: Try adding the .MsmqTransport()

Comment: Hi, You shouldn't post your thoughts as answers.. rather edit the original question.

Comment: this is also a crazy way to use a fluent api

Comment: iwayneo are you referring to the "config="? If so that was simply a way to locate which call was failing.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, looks like a reference to ncqrs.NserviceBus is causing it to go wrong even though I'm not actually using it yet

Answer (score 1):

Looks like manually adding the Assemblies in the overload to With() did the trick, not sure what's upsetting it but that's for another day